# Silverlight DLR Support

Tags: silverlight, dynamic-language-runtime

I have been looking for a list of languages supporting the DLR in silverlight. All I can find at the moment are IronRuby and IronPython.

I have also seen CSScript which is a C# scripting engine, but not sure if it works from within Silverlight (http://www.csscript.net).

Basically, I would like to introduce scripting capabilities to one of my silverlight apps, and I would like to know what options I have of language.

Can anyone suggest other alternatives?

Thanks,
Shane.